# preserve dropdown value when return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

for the below drop down list, when i select any value, I have to do a confirm (OK/Cancel), if user selects Cancel, I need to retain the previous state. What's happening is when hitting on Cancel and doing `return false;`, the new value is getting selected, and not retaining the previous value. How can i make sure the previous value is selected, when cancel is clicked. I tried using the below code but doesn't seem to help:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('mySelect');
ele.selected = ele.defaultSelected;            
return false;

<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Question is tagged as 'jquery' but you don't seem to be using it, are you?

Comment: i am ok with a jquery solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#mySelect").mousedown(function() {
         var old_value = $("#mySelect").val();
         var confirm_selection = confirm("Are you sure?");
         if (!confirm_selection)
         {
            $("#mySelect").val(old_value);
            return false;
         }
    }); 

});

</script>
```

Just change the confirm text to whatever you like.

Have to use mousedown() instead of change() as when using change the function will be called AFTER the new item is selected and thus there is no way to know what previous item was selected.

Comment: There could be an issue if user do id using the keyboard. It's not frequent, but it could happen.

Comment: This code works, but is firing the onchange event as we are setting the value back. Is there a way to stop it? I am assuming my qn may not be logical, as the event is rightly firing, but am just thinking if there is another way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

I think -I think-, the only solution is to keep previous selected value and set it again on cancel. You can easyly get an set the value of your select with `val()`.

Briefly:

```
prev_val = $('#myselect').val();

if (cancel) {
    $('#myselect').val(prev_val);
}
```

Comment: your prev_val will give you the currently selected value (which is not exactly the previous state)

Comment: I oversimplify the code for the answer, but I mean, you must store `prev_val` before the user action.